# Add image in category menu before category-name Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, menu

I'm create new attribute is small image for category.In admin i have save image for category-1 then i get this image in menu category but image exist for all category.Although in admin i just save image for category-1.Same this image  red box is category save image in admin.pls see help me.
I Will add image in file custom Topmenu.php
 `

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\objectManager::getInstance();
        $cate = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
        $id = substr($child->getId(),14);            
        $item  = $cate->load($id);
   $image = $id !='' ? '<img src="'.$item->getSmallImageUrl().'" width="30" height="30">' :'';            
        $outermostClassCode = '';
        $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

        if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
            $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
            $child->setClass($outermostClass);
        }

        if (count($colBrakes) && $colBrakes[$counter]['colbrake']) {
            $html .= '</ul></li><li class="column"><ul>';
        }

        $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
        $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '>'.$image.'<span>' . $this->escapeHtml(
            $child->getName()
        ) . '</span></a>' . $this->_addSubMenu(
            $child,
            $childLevel,
            $childrenWrapClass,
            $limit
        ) . '</li>';
        $itemPosition++;
        $counter++;`
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

```
$image = $id !='' ? '<img src="'.$item->getSmallImageUrl().'" width="30" height="30">' :'';
```

**with**

```
 $image = $id !='' ? '<img src="'.$item->getImageUrl().'" width="30" height="30">' :'';
```

Answer (score -1):

You should change

```
$cate = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category'); to  $cate = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
```